# why am i redirected to my users controller if i try to sign in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a link on my homepage - directing to my devise sign-in page

```
<%= link_to "Sign in", new_user_session_path %>
```

When I press it now I am however getting an error (it says it does not recognizes @user in my `userscontroller`). But I do not understand why I am redirected to my `users controller`, I should just go to my log in page right?

My routes are set up like this:

```
  Rails.application.routes.draw do
    get 'comments/create'
    resources :users, only: [:show]

    devise_for :users
    resources :topics do
      resources :posts, except: [:index] 
    end

    resources :post, only: [] do
      resources :comments, only: [:create, :destroy]
      resources :favorites, only: [:create, :destroy]
      post '/up-vote' => 'votes#up_vote', as: :up_vote
      post '/down-vote' => 'votes#down_vote', as: :down_vote
    end
    get 'about' => 'welcome#about'
    root to: 'welcome#index'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your route setup is correct, I believe you're being re-directed to your users controller because you're already signed in.

You can customise the page you're redirected to by modifying your `ApplicationController` as follows:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    '/route_or_helper'
  end
end
```

A good way to quickly test this is by opening an Incognito Tab in Chrome or similar (so that you're not logged in) which will then show you the login page.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Katherine but I already checked this. Also when Im not signed in i get the error...

Comment: what uri does rake routes give you for new_user_session?

Comment: Ah OK my mistake! Any chance you could provide the full log output from the request and the redirect to get a better idea what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there could be 2 conflicting routes.

The URL path for the users controller `show` action has the format `/users/:id`, where `:id` is a dynamic segment. This is configured by the `resources :users, only: [:show]` line in `routes.rb`.

The URL path for sign in (`new_user_session_path`) is `/users/sign_in`. This is configured by the `devise_for :users` line in `routes.rb`.

These 2 URL paths conflict. `/users/sign_in` matches the users controller format `/users/:id`, where the `:id` segment equals `sign_in`. Currently Rails will route requests for `/users/sign_in` to the `UsersController#show` action.

Try moving the `devise_for :users` line in `routes.rb` above the `resources :users, only: [:show]` line to change the routes' priority order. This will mean `/users/sign_in` URL requests are routed to the correct controller (the controller that's provided by Devise).